Limits of composite functions and directions of limits
Consider $\lim_{x \to 0^+}(1/\sqrt[3]{x})$. It is a right-hand limit of a composite function. Here is my approach for solving it.
Let $y = \sqrt[3]{x}$. We can show that $\lim_{x \to 0^+}(\sqrt[3]{x}) = 0$. Or in other words, as $x \to 0^+$, $y \to 0$. Substituting these results into the original expression we get $\lim_{y \to 0}(1/y)$. The result is that the limit does not exist since it has different values when y approaches zero from the right and left.
This is false, since we can see from the graph of $1/\sqrt[3]{x}$ that it clearly approaches positive infinity from the right. Something about my approach is wrong.
Here's what is wrong. We can't just say that as $x \to 0^+$, $y \to 0$. We have to be more specific. Looking at the graph of $y = \sqrt[3]{x}$, we can see that the y values start above zero and go down to zero when x starts to the right of zero and goes left to zero. So we could say that as $x \to 0^+$, $y \to 0^+$.
Then plugging those values into the original expression, we get $\lim_{y \to 0^+}(1/y) = \infty$ as expected.
Consider $\lim_{x \to 0}(1/x^2)$. It is a limit of a composite function, approaching from both sides. Here is my approach for solving it.
Let $y = x^2$. We can see from the graph of the parabola that as $x \to 0$ from either side, $y \to 0+$. Substituting these results into the original expression we get $\lim_{y \to 0+}(1/y) = \infty$.
This all seems fairly intuitive, but it's not rigorous. Is there a rigorous way to show that as an input value approaches a specified value from a specified direction(s), that the output value approaches another specified value from another specified direction(s)? If there was such a thing, it would be very useful for evaluating limits of composite functions by substitution. Limits, as they are currently defined, do not show what I am looking for. They only show that as an input value approaches a specified value from a specified direction(s), that the output value approaches another specified value from some unspecified direction(s).

Generally, it can be proved, that if $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0$ and $f$ is not zero in some deleted neighbourhood of $x_0$, then $\exists \lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac {1}{f(x)}=\infty$.
